# Freelance Business Plan

Tags: business-plan

I plan on working as a Freelance developer. But here in the UAE, one has to acquire a Freelance license. For this to be granted, you have to submit a business plan. The question is, how should a freelance business plan be written in comparison to a normal business plan. For example, as a freelancer, you may or may not always get clients. As opposed to some other forms of business, which can constantly offer their services. How will I be able to convince the approving body that as a freelancer, I can make a good business and earn some money.

Comment: A business plan shouldn't be understood as some formality to please the "approving body". The main recipient is yourself, your livelihood depends on it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking there is not really a difference. A business plan should outline how you expect your business to run. It will always differ from the result once you actually go through with it.

Then, why bother?

1. To an informed reader, it should outline the premises on which you want to build your business, and reveal potential flaws.
2. After you started your business, you can use this for controlling your actual progress and see where you need to put in additional effort.

If you recon you will not always have clients, your plan should show how you cope with that. It is ok, some businesses (freelance or not) have downtime and are still viable. It is also important to show that you are aware of those risks and what you plan to do to minimize them.

Comment: Great. This is very informative. Thanks. Do I have to indicate a list of possible clients as a freelancer? For example, at the time that I am writing the business plan, the client I plan on first working with is not yet sure that we will proceed with the work.

Comment: Yes, opportunities/existing business is usually a part of the plan, as well as risks. If this is a official requirement there ought to examples of successful plans.